# Create a excel report from a SAS table.

Tags: excel, sas, report, sas-ods

Hello and thanks for your time,

Im trying to make a excel report from a SAS table.

I need to place different tables on the same report sheet. ¿Its is possible to choose the lines and colums where I want my table to be placed?.

```
options center;
ods listing close;
ods tagsets.ExcelXP path="C:\" 
file="MAY..xls" style=statistical;

%let page=%sysfunc(putn(tryal.cups));
ods tagsets.ExcelXP options(sheet_name="&page");
proc print data=tryal.cups5 noobs label split='*';
run; quit;
```

I would also like to set the width of each columns. If tryed several things but I canot make it.

Thanks¡

Comment: you should try looking into panelling in msoffice2k_x tagsets (http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/msoffice2k/index.html#paneling). This should help you place multiple tables on single sheet. For getting the tables to start on your desired column and row you can alter the output since that would be simple html..Otherwise you could look into proc template.